# Flex XMLListCollection Iteration Concatenating Collected Values

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

I am working in flex builder 3 with an XMLListCollection and have run into this (should be simple) parsing snag...

The XMLListCollection Data:

```
<data>
    <term name="NUMBERS">
        <alt_form name="1"/>
    </term>
    <term name="LETTERS">
        <alt_form name="A"/>
        <alt_form name="B"/>
        <alt_form name="C"/>
    </term>
</data>
```

The AS Function:

```
private function interateThroughXML(myList:XMLListCollection):void {
    for each (var node : XML in myList){
        trace(node.@name + " is my list item name");
        if (node.alt_form.@name != null) {
            trace(node.alt_form.@name + " is my list SUB item name");
        }
    }
}
```

The Output:

> NUMBERS is my list item name
>   1 is my list SUB item name
>   LETTERS is my list item name
>   ABC is my list SUB item name

Note that the three subnode name values have been concatenated as "ABC". What do I need to do differently in order to capture the sub-item name values (A, B, and C) individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the subnodes, too.  Calling `node.alt_form` returns an XMLList, so iterate over that:

```
private function iterateThroughXML(myList:XMLListCollection):void {
    for each (var node : XML in myList){
        trace(node.@name + " is my list item name");
        for each (var subnode : XML in node.alt_form) {
            if (subnode.@name != null) {
                trace(subnode.@name + " is my list SUB item name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why that didn't occur to me, I don't know... Your example plugged-and-played like a charm. Thanks a bunch Matt!